# What's the proper way to handle libraries which are not typed in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am using some libraries, which are not typed and am getting warnings. What's the proper way to handle it - should I add some configurations or tslint ignore on a line basis? Or may be create some dummy typings or generate some proper typings myself?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information.

If these libraries are public, you can check DefinitelyTyped, and see if there are public typescript definitions for them. For example, for jquery, you can install:

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

In any case, you shouldn't be getting any warnings. Can you post some of those? The typescript compiler should be able to extract information from the .js files, as JavaScript is also valid TypeScript.

Comment: this one failes for example: npm install @types/ethereumjs-wallet

Comment: That library doesn't have a @types definition, not every library has. Anyway, which errors/warnings are you getting? Can you post some?